# Angularjs how to stop infinity scroll when server has no more data to send

Tags: angularjs

Based on [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/) example which I have modified with an Ajax request to get the data Im struggling to find a way to stop it when the server has no more data to send.

I have tried to add a boolean variable in a `service`, and a `$watch` method in the `directive` but it is not working.

Is there a simple way to to achieve that ?

This is not my code but if there is no easy answer I can post my code with the changes I have done.

thanks for your help.

```
<div id="fixed" when-scrolled="loadMore()">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items">{{i.id}}</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

function Main($scope) {
    $scope.data = { comments : [] }
    $scope.loadMore =  function(){
        $http({
            url: '/comment/next',
            method: "POST"
        })
        .success(function(data){
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                $scope.data.comments.push(data[i]);
            }        
        });
    }
}

angular.module('scroll', []).directive('whenScrolled', function() {
    return function(scope, elm, attr) {
        var raw = elm[0];

        elm.bind('scroll', function() {
            if (raw.scrollTop + raw.offsetHeight >= raw.scrollHeight) {
                scope.$apply(attr.whenScrolled);
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: We need your code. :)

Comment: How would you do it with this code ? My code is a real mess...

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess as to a solution without seeing more of your code (specifically what is returned by `$http` results), but I believe this sort of thing could work, depending on the structure of a comment object.

```
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.data = { comments : [] }
    $scope.scrollComplete = false;
    $scope.loadMore =  function(){            
        if($scope.scrollComplete || $scope.loading) { return; }
        $scope.loading = true;
        $http({
            url: '/comment/next',
            method: "POST"
        })
        .success(function(data){
            for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                var totalComments = $scope.data.comments.length;
                if($scope.data.comments[totalComments - 1].someID === data[i].someID){
                    $scope.scrollComplete = true;
                }else{
                    $scope.data.comments.push(data[i]);
                }
            } 
            $scope.loading = false;       
        }).error(function(){ $scope.loading = false });
    }
}
```

Just bear in mind that a solution like this isn't really elegant. What I like to do is allow an item ID to be passed to the API (i.e. your /comment/next), and treat that as the last grabbed item. So the API will only give me back everything after that. Using that method, you would simply have to pass the last comment ID to the API.

Comment: What you're saying in your comment seams to be a nice solution, but that means I have to load all the comments to know which one is the last one.. I might add that value in the JSON returned by the server. Thanks for your help